# Word for the person who only plans

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

What is the word for the person who only plans for something? Or the person only starts something and then forgets it or does not complete it.

Comment: Welcome! Do you mean a someone who thinks about something a lot but never does it, like a daydreamer? Or someone who simply lack the ability to execute what he or she planned?

Comment: @RexYuan, No, I mean someone who wishes and dreams aything, he plans about it, he starts it and then left it in the midway and never completes it.

Comment: In that case @Raj's answer is correct

Comment: A person who only plans is different from a person who doesn't complete things. Decide what you want to ask about, then [edit] this so that it's only asking about one thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [quitter](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/quitter)?

> a person who gives up easily and does not finish a task they have started

Answer (score 1):

To me they're not so much a quitter as a ***dallier***, which is one who has a *dalliance* with a specific plan or commitment, that is, they [**daly**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Dallier): "To consider or occupy oneself with something in a careless or unserious fashion."  This not quite the same as *dilly-dallier*, which implies pure time wasted, instead of the time spent on plans abandoned of a *dalliance.*  (In terms of people who start things and do not finish them, *dalliance* is most commonly used for unserious romantic liasons, but it's by no means only that.)

Similar is *dabbler*, though it implies less commitment.

If it's a new area of interest for the person, you might call them a ***dilletante***, which is "a person who cultivates an area of interest, such as the arts, without real commitment or knowledge."

In general that person is ***irresolute***, in that they are hesistant to *follow-through* their initial plans, though I know of no term specifically for an irresolute person.